# Prove that $f\in L^2(\mu)$ is star-cyclic vector for $N_\mu$ ,where $N_\mu f=zf$, if and only if $\mu(\{x:\,f(x)=0\})=0$

Tags: real-analysis, spectral-theory

Let $\mu $ be a regular Borel  measure on $\mathbb C$ with compact support, define $N_\mu$ on $   L^2(\mu)$ by $N_\mu f=zf$ for each $f\in L^2(\mu)$. Prove that    $f\in L^2(\mu)$ is star-cyclic vector for $N_\mu$ if and only if $\mu(\{x:\,f(x)=0\})=0$

**My attempt**

**1:** I've proved $N_\mu $ is normal

**2:** If $E$ is the spectral measure for $N_\mu $, then $E(\Delta)=\chi_{\Delta}(N_\mu) $

**3:** $1$ is a star-cyclic vector for $N_\mu$

**4:** $N_\mu= \int \lambda \, dE(\lambda) $

Any help is greatly appreciated